# How can I store an array of ancestor ids as a List<string> in C# for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a POCO C# class that has a list of ancestor ids. I want to store this list as `List<string>` so that my domain project doesn't need a dependency on the mongodb c# driver. This worked fine for my Id property. I was able to use the **RegisterClassMap** method (from the [MongoDB C# Driver docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Classlevelserializationoptions)) for the Id property:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Employee>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

But I can't figure out how to specify that an array of strings (or a `List<string>` in my case) is actually an array of **ObjectIds**.

Help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what I was looking for.  Many thanks to [craiggwilson's post on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-csharp/hP0bGPyfJhs), for without reading that thread I wouldn't have thought to try the following.

For the following "Content" class in C#

```
public class Content
{
    public List<string> AncestorIds { get; set; }

    public string ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

It worked to execute the following code on application start:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Content>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();

    // Single ObjectId represented in C# as a string
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.ParentId).SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);

    // Array of ObjectIds represented in C# as a List<string>
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.AncestorIds).SetSerializationOptions(new ArraySerializationOptions(new RepresentationSerializationOptions(BsonType.ObjectId)));
});
```